# Adding a public github repo as Submodule in a private repository would make the submodule repo as Private

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a **private Github** repo and I want to add a **public Github** repo as a **Submodule** in that repo. My question is that If I add the public repo as submodule, would the public repo become private?. Because I want to make changes in the public repo and don't want anyone to access it.

Comment: That sounds like something unlikely and also like something that you can easily test yourself.

Comment: I can test it but I want suggestions how can I achieve it with or without submodules. Is there any other way without submodules to achieve this in Git ??

Comment: You did not ask this question in your posting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort. What the question is about can very easily be tested.

Answer (score 3):

No your public repository will not become private.
Only Github manage your repository visibility.

This is exactly what git submodules are used for, having unrelated repositories as subdirectories. [See the doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

And do not forget to commit your `.gitmodules` file.